How to get the name of a removed file in Google Drive using their REST API
The Google Drive API v3 offers an endpoint to track the changes that happen to folder in a Google Drive account, named changes.list.
However, when reporting a file removal, the call informs only of the fileId, but not of tis fileNamre nor path.
Here is an example of the call I make to sync the changes:
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes?Content-Type=application/json&Accept=application/json&includeRemoved=true&pageToken=2556
An for a removed files the call returns the following json:
    {
    "kind": "drive#changeList",
    "newStartPageToken": "2560",
    "changes": [
        {
            "kind": "drive#change",
            "removed": true,
            "fileId": "1T1tBUHRzarIMLgKAN_3QVusWOYU1oVXY9Q9jeg1DG-8",
            "time": "2024-08-26T14:33:10.658Z",
            "type": "file",
            "changeType": "file"
        }
    ]}

But, the name of the file is not stated anywhere, and trying to query the file with the specified Id (using the files.get call), returns the following:
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "File not found: 1T1tBUHRzarIMLgKAN_3QVusWOYU1oVXY9Q9jeg1DG-8.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "File not found: 1T1tBUHRzarIMLgKAN_3QVusWOYU1oVXY9Q9jeg1DG-8.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "notFound",
                "location": "fileId",
                "locationType": "parameter"
            }
        ]
    }
}

which makes sense because the file no longer exists.
Is there any way to retrieve the name of a removed file?

Since you have already obtained the fileId using files.list, why not use files.get afterwards?

That's very strange, because when I was saying in my question that "trying to query the file with the specified Id returns" a 404 error, I was precisely using the files.get call. I'm going to edit the question to clarify this, but basically, calling files.get returns a "404 File not found" error.

I see. Let me modify my answer as this issue is already related to google vault api.

May I know if you are using a workspace account or just a Gmail account? If you are only using a Gmail account, then I am afraid that you will not have access to Google Vault (as file management for deleted files not in the trash anymore is under Google Vault). If you have a workspace account, then you should contact Google Workspace Support for this matter.

I'm using a regular Gmail account. I'm developing an iOS app for general use where users will be able to sync the app data in a folder in their Google Drive, and as they may use several devices I need to identify when a file has been deleted from a device and delete it in the current one, but as the deletion change only reports the fileId and not the name, i'm having a hard time identifying which file has been deleted.

After carefull investigation of the API documentation, I've arrived to the conclusion that there is no parameter that we can add to the changes.list endpoint to get the name or path for removed files.
Therefore, As I'm developing an app tha synces changes to a google drive account with the local file system, to be able to process the removal of files, I've ended up maintaining a dictionary with the fileId as the key, and the full path of each file as value. That way, each time a I get notified about a removed operation I know which phisical file it refers to and I'm able to delete it.
